# Decomposition of tall and slim tensors

Tags: tensors, tensor-rank

Assume a tall and slim tensor with 3 dimensions: $\mathbf{T}\in \mathbb{R}^{a \times b \times c}$ where $a=10000$, $b=5000$, and $c=5$. The tensor is very sparsely filled.

I want to do tensor completion by interpolating from known sparse values and with this I turn to simple canonical decomposition:

$\mathbf{T}_{xyz} = \sum_{k=1}^f \mathbf{A}_{xk} \cdot \mathbf{B}_{yk} \cdot \mathbf{C}_{zk}$,

where we have component tensors $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R} ^{a \times f}, \mathbf{B}\in \mathbb{R} ^{b \times f}, \mathbf{C}\in \mathbb{R} ^{c \times f}$. Then, I have an objective function which iterates over available data to fill in the component tensors.

As a novice in tensor factorization, my question is: Say, if $f=20$, I will have a component matrix $\mathbf{C}\in \mathbb{R} ^{5 \times 20}$. Then, thinking of (and getting puzzled with) matrix rank and SVD, this matrix can have a max. rank of 5, so what is the use of using $f=20$ ? In other words, is it of any use to have a larger $f$ than one of the dimensions in the tensor $\mathbf{T}$?

Thanks for your comments ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The multilinear ranks never exceed the dimensions, but tensor rank may. In your case (i.e., if we assume that you have a random sparse tensor), the multilinear rank is ($\min(a,f)$,$\min(a,f)$,$\min(a,f)$)=(20,20,5).

The practical way to compute canonical decomposition: Since $a$, $b$, and $f$ are not too large, you can first compute the Higher-Order Singular Value Decomposition of $T$(the sparsity can be ignored). Then compute canonical decomposition for the core tensor (it has dimensions $20\times 20\times 5$). And, finally, the canonical decomposition of the initial tensor can be recovered from the canonical decomposition of the core tensor.

Comment: The dimensions can also be on the order of 10^9 * 10^6 * 5. This was a toy example. So, as far as I understand it may be ok to choose f=20 in this case although c=5. Is there a practical test to verify this prior to choosing f? (btw, since I have < 15 reps, I cannot vote your answer)

Comment: The tensor rank is NP-hard problem, i.e., the formula does not exist. In general the tensor rank can be significantly higher than the largest tensor dimension. On the other hand, I suppose that you do not need, sometimes it is okay, to try a to compute the canonical decomposition of a substensor (sometimes it is possible to choose a "dense" subtensor of a sparse tensor) and to try to compute the decomposition for different values of $f$. This may give a good guess for $f$ for the initial tensor. If you are able to estimate the multilinear rank, then this will also give a bound on $f$.